# RegExp (in Javascript) minimum length and minimum length after pipes, if pipes are present

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that requires a minimum of 4 characters, and, if separated by pipes, that there are at least 4 characters present after each pipe.

For example, these entries would be valid:

```
weather|bronco|flock
weather
```

Whereas, these ones would not:

```
red
weather|br||flock|red
```

What I have so far almost works, except that it allows users adding only 1 alphanumeric before entering in another pipe:

```
^((?:(?!([|][|])|^[|]|[|]\\s|[|]$).)*)
```

Comment: what characters are allowed to be present after the pipes, and have you tried anything

Comment: Do you really need regex?

Comment: Have you tried to make a regex? How far have you gotten? Can we see it? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: closest to making it work: ^((?:(?!([|][|])|^[|]|[|]\\s|[|]$).)*)

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to do without a regex:

```
'foo|bar||baz'.split('|').every(function(elem) {
    return elem.length >= 4;
});
```

But if you insist on a regex, this should work:

```
/^[^|]{4,}(?:\|[^|]{4,})*$/
```

Comment: This is very very close. It checks for the minimum 4 characters but is not valid if I enter in length of characters after a pipe

Comment: @user2581889: What's your test string?

Comment: That regex is more complicated than it needs to be.  `/^[^|]{4,}(?:\|[^|]{4,})*$/` does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

if you really need regex, you may use the following

```
^(\w{4,}\|)+\w{4,}$
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HxaQj/)

I assumed you need `\w` between pipes. It could be changed to other symbols. (You may replace it with `[^|]` for example, if you want allow anything except pipe).

Without regex:

```
valid = true;
for(word in "string|with|pipes".split()) {
    if(word.length < 4) {

        valid = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you you think he shouldn't use a regex, he's validating a string

Comment: why do you recommend without regex? I just had another user blaming me for doing that way, lol!

Comment: because regex are to heavy instrument for this.

Comment: @user2581889, added forgotten '\' and DEMO

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = "weather|br||flock|red".split('|'); //["weather", "br", "", "flock", "red"]
var valid = true;
//now iterate array and check if any item is < 4 length

for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i].length < 4 ) valid = false;
}

console.log(valid);
```

Comment: He wants a regex, also why take the time to split and then validate when you can do it in one step

Comment: I want to say yes, but the reason I haven't answered yet is because his terms are very unspecific, answering would require me to make a lot of assumtions

Comment: @aaronman :) I was just trying to help him as I could, you can try your way, no offence

Comment: I would prefer to perform validation in one step and not have to iterate thru an array - although that would work it is not feasable in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this pattern:

```
var regex = /^(?:\w{4,}\|?)+$/
```

or with more constraint:

```
var regex = /^(?:\w{4,}(?:\|(?!$))?)+$/
```

Comment: @user2581889: http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E(%3F%3A%5Cw%7B4%2C%7D%5C%7C%3F)%2B%24&input=weather%7Cbronco%7Cflock%0Aweather%0Ared%0Aweather%7Cbr%7C%7Cflock%7Cred

Comment: However, this came very close as well: ^((?:(?!([|][|])|^[|]|[|]\\s|[|]$).)*)